# Combine multiple es6 classes into single library using rollup js

Tags: rollup, rollupjs, umd

How can I import `a.js` and `b.js` and export as combined `bundle.js` in UMD format using rollupjs?

Here is the example:

```
//a.js
export default class A {
...
}

//b.js
export default class B {
...
}
```

My current `rollup.config.js` is:

```
export default [
  {
    input: ["path/a.js", "path/b.js"],
    output: {
      file: "path/bundle.js",
      format: "umd",
      name: "Bundle"
    },
    plugins: [
      // list of plugins
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this is not working as intended.

Anything wrong with this config?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need a file to tie them together. So along with `a.js` and `b.js`, have a `main.js` that looks like this:

```
import A from './a';
import B from './b';

export default {
  A,
  B,
};
```

Then update your `rollup.config.js` with `input: path/main.js`.